# Using arrays with structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I'm trying to make couple of arrays out of a structure.
I'm having difficulties in getting the values for every array ( for example I want to get 6 different arrays from a structure but I only get one array and then the program stops to the final stage).
Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
#define NUM_OF_PLAYERS 6
typedef struct player
{
char name[20];
float height;
float avr_points;
int tshirt_num;
 };



int main()
{
_flushall();
struct player players[NUM_OF_PLAYERS];
int i;
for (i=0 ; i<NUM_OF_PLAYERS ; i++);
{
    printf("\nenter the name of the player, height in cm, \navrage points            per game and number of his tshirt\n"); 
    scanf("%s", &players[i].name);
    scanf("%f", &players[i].height);
    scanf("%f", &players[i].avr_points);
    scanf("%d", &players[i].tshirt_num);
    _flushall();
}
```

Comment: first thing, the typedef either 1) needs a final name before the ';' or 2) remove the 'typedef' modifier

Comment: what are you expecting the calls to '_flushall();' to accomplish?  the flush operation is only for output, not input streams.  So it has no effect on stdin.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra `;` which terminates your for-loop.

```
for (i=0 ; i<NUM_OF_PLAYERS ; i++);
                                  ^
```

This is essentially equal to

```
for (i=0 ; i<NUM_OF_PLAYERS ; i++) {}
```

So the for-loop has an empty body, and all scanf's are executed only once, outside the loop.

Comment: ........................................
MY BAD...........................
Thank you VERY much!
I was stuck on this for couple of hours.....

Comment: also note that the scanf's are placing data past the end of the definition of 'players' array as 'i' is already 7 when exiting the 'for' loop.  I.E. undefined behaviour that can/will lead to a seg fault event.